# Configuring Wamp Server to Run WML Pages

Tags: php, configuration, mime-types, wampserver, wml

my server is wamp 2.0 (apache 2.2.11), I am trying to run WML page, but each time the emulator show me a download dialogue.

I have tried to add the WML MIME Types as below and restarted the server:

```
text/vnd.wap.wml wml
text/vnd.wap.wmlscript wmls
image/vnd.wap.wbmp wbmp
```

but nothing happened.
also I tried to change the header in the PHP page to be WML :

```
header("Content-type: text/vnd.wap.wml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

it doesn't work.

any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Apache Web server installed on your machine. So now we will tell you how to enable WAP functionality in your Apache web server.

So locate Apache's file httpd.conf which is usually in /etc/httpd/conf, and add the following lines to the file and restart the server:

```
AddType text/vnd.wap.wml .wml
AddType text/vnd.wap.wmlscript .wmls
AddType application/vnd.wap.wmlc .wmlc
AddType application/vnd.wap.wmlscriptc .wmlsc
AddType image/vnd.wap.wbmp .wbmp
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/wml/wml_quick_guide.htm